# Ionic2 PWA + Firebase Hosting not working

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-hosting, progressive-web-apps

I try to host an Ionic2 App as a PWA on Firebase Hosting - but it is not working.

```
ionic build --prod browser
```

then I initialize the firebase project in the *platforms/browser* directory

```
firebase init
```

then I upload the app

```
firebase deploy
```

But it is still not working.

#### I always get this page:

[image: Firebase hosting default page]

Comment: Try overwriting the index html that was created in the **`init`** phase. As stated in this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488613/5995040), the `index.html` file is created with a templated "Welcome...." message. AFAIK, this will prompt and ask your consent to overwrite if there is an index file upon deployment. This can easily be resolve by replacing the templated html with your own html file. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks - it was not the problem. But based on your hint I found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake happend at Step 2. I choose *dist* as public directory based on some angular tutorials.

## Solution

#### Step 1

Initialize firebase in your **main** directory

```
firebase init
```

#### Step 2

What do you want to use as your public directory? **www**

#### Step 3

Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? **Yes**

#### Step 4

File www/index.html already exists. Overwrite? **No**

#### Step 5

```
ionic build --prod
```

#### Step 6

```
firebase deploy
```