# firebase CLI will not recognize current directory for 'firebase init'

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am following a tutorial on Ionic Angular and it has come to the point where the instructor is having me publish my code to Firebase Hosting. First I used NPM to install the Firebase CLI. Then I was instructed to use the `firebase init` command. The issue is that the CLI doesn't seem to recognize the current directory that is selected in my terminal.

I run: `cd /Users/MyUserName/myProjectsFolder/myProject/`
Then I run `firebase init` and it displays:

> You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:
>
> /Users/MyUserName

When I would expect it to read:

> You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:
>
> /Users/MyUserName/myProjectsFolder/myProject

A little bit of googling found this page:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/

Which includes this passage:

> To initialize a new project directory, change directories in the terminal to your desired project directory and run: firebase init

Based on this I would expect the steps I took to work.

I am confused. Has anyone ever run into this behavior? Can anyone think of a way to get the CLI to function as expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Got to folder:

   /Users/Username/
2. Search for a file with name of firebase.json and Delete it.
3. Reinstall firebase tool with this command (--unsafeper- to avoid
   permissions error messages & use sudo):

   $ sudo npm install --unsafeper- -g firebase-tools
4. Then, go to your pubilc folder (you have to create one) which
   contains your HTML, JS, images and CSS files and use this command:

   $ sudo firebase init

   $ sudo firebase deploy
5. The reset is easy and as mentioned in the firebase
           docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you must have initiliazed a project in some parent directory (of this myProject folder) in the past. Somehow firebase sees that project in that directory rather than initializing a new project in the current path.

**Solution:**
Check the parent directories of the path where you want to initialize a firebase project now. Delete / Move the firebase files from that folder and then you should be able to initialize a project in the current directory.

**For example:**

I also faced the same problem.
I was trying to initialize a project in this path:

```
D:\Work\Projects\myProject
```

But somehow it always got initialized in this path:

```
D:\Work
```

After some searching it turned out that the reason was that I had initialized a project in
D:\Work directory. I moved those files to another folder and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem and windows not able to recognize the firebase. I don't know the exact reason why it was behaving in such a manner but it solved the problem.

1) I installed the firebase-tools using a command on command prompt

> npm install -g firebase-tools

and it didn't work.
2) I restarted the machine.
3) then again I executed the same command from step 1) npm install -g firebase-tools
and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to do this and discovered a command that allows "firebase" as a command.`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash` This will allow `$ firebase login` and `$ firebase init` to work.

Answer (score 0):

one you should write that in cmd

```
  firebase login
```

if the cmd response " Already logged in as hello@example.com"
you should to regenerate the authentication of this email

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. After checking the log I figured out that the Authentication token was expired from my firebase cli login session. So I logged out and Logged-In again to the firebase cli using `Firebase logout` And `firebase login` command. Problem solved.

To check out your issue go to firebase log using `firebase-debug.log` command.
And take required steps.