# Firebase Application deployment

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am newbie Angular developer. I have developed a small application and trying to deploy it on the firebase. below are the steps performed by me.

1. Ran firebase init
2. selected 'Hosting service', selected dist as public folder
3. selected Y for Configure as a single-page app option.
4. created the build of application and deployed on the firebase.

I was able to deploy application successfully by firebase URL is showing me default "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complet Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" page.

Some of the posts say that firebase overwrites /dist/index.html file which didn't happen for me.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: Make sure the HTML you expect to see is in `public/index.html` before calling `firebase deploy`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486069/firebase-not-running-index-html-file

Comment: for some reasons, build command is creating one extra(project name) folder inside dist folder.   when i moved content of that folder to parent folder it worked fine,

Comment: IF you have build the project, ad then again ran the project using ng serve, then the dist folder is removed.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360477/angular-6-0-firebase-hosting-deploy-not-working/51809723#51809723