# Firebase deployment (react app) - generates a blank screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment

I am trying to deploy my react app to Firebase (using firebase-tools).

The app was generated using this generator (which has deployment instructions in the readme). I followed them, but they didn't flag that Firebase overrides the index html, so they initial step replaced my html in the build file with the Firebase override. I copied my src/index.html back to the build file and re-ran the init, build and deploy calls.

I have an intercom script on the home page - the only part of the page that renders is the intercom icon. The rest of the page is blank.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486069/firebase-not-running-index-html-file). Like this user, I had to remove the predeploy script from my firebase.json because it was generating eslint errors.

The [facebook create-react-app advice](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) for Firebase hosting is to add an additional script to the firebase.json with:

```
"headers": [
      {"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}
    ],
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't change anything.

I tried removing, reinstalling npm and then cleaning the cache (in the functions folder). I have noticed that reinstalling node modules does not result in a functions/node_modules/eslint folder. I'm not sure why.

Others have suggested chrome/devtools/application/clear storage/clear site data. I have tried it but nothing changes.

Some posts attribute the problem to firebase-tools - although more recent posts suggest that the error that gave rise to that solution has now been remedied.

Has anyone found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In firebase.json - change public from 'build' to 'dist'

"hosting": {
    "public": "dist",

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I'm trying to deploy my react native and just a blank screen appears. But locally, it works normally with the command "npx serve dist"

firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
   "public": "dist",
   "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
   ],
   "rewrites": [
       {
         "source": "**",
         "destination": "/index.html"
       }
   ]
}
```