# Firebase hosting showing welcome page after deploying angular 6 app?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to develop the angular 6 apps, but after deploying firebase showing only welcome page.

Here are the steps I have taken to deploy.

1. installed firebase-tools
2. ng build --prod (in my app)
3. firebase init
4. Are you ready to proceed? (Y/n) y
5. (*) Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
6. What do you want to use as your public directory? (public) dist
7. Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N) y
8. File dist/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) y
9. Firebase initialization complete!
10. In this step, I have deleted dist folder and run `ng build --prod` again
11. angular build app in a subfolder inside `dist` directory hence I copied all the content from the subdirectory which contains index.html to `dist/`.
12. firebase deploy
13. firebase open hosting:site

but after doing all that I am still getting welcome page in the link.

What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:
 8. File dist/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) N
 and open link to your app in incognito mode. Seriously, I stuck for hours because this firebase index got cached in my case, so this was the reason why I could't see my app after deploy.

Comment: Why does it work on incognito mode??

Comment: You can also just hold shift and click refresh which will remove the cache for that page

Comment: @XXIV Because the issue is that the defualt "Firebase Hosting Complete" page is cached in the browser (in other words stored locally) so instead of actually looking at the contents of the new index.html file, it's just using the locally stored one. Incognito mode doesn't use cached pages

Answer (score 5):

**The Problem is:**
firebase is looking for the `index.html` file, sometimes it is not present directly in the `dist` directory

**Solution:**
update the `public` path in the `firebase.json` to `"public":"dist/ProjectName"` or path to the `index.html` file in the `dist` folder

**Example**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/<YourProjectName>",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/dist/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, I had to change the "public" value to "build/web", but that worked! Maybe because I am using Flutter to build my app?

Answer (score 2):

Browser cache was my issue as well. As mentioned above, try in incognito or use proxysite.com (very useful website) to avoid browser cache

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was initializing firebase inside the project directory (`src`). Just check the directory you are in. It should be on the top level.

After you build it and try to deploy it, it will be the same since the web page has been cached. So to make sure use in `incognito`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to change `public` to `dist` in firebase.json so it pointed to my dist folder (rather than the public folder which contains the holding page) after I added Firebase Functions to my project:

```
"hosting": {
   "public": "dist",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the path on terminal .if the problem still exists then delete firebase auto created folders and deploy the project

Answer (score 0):

Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No

- Wrote public/404.html
  ? File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No

This error is generated by index.html inside public folder of your website folder.

Answer (score 0):

The welcome page is an automatically generated index.html file found in **public** folder. I replaced that file with my own index.html file, then use `firebase deploy --only hosting` commands to update the changes.

Answer (score 0):

first you should login firebase login
after that write command firesbe init

first steps

1. What do you want to use as your public directory? (public) dist/projectname
2. File dist/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) N

after completing the process
you should run (`npm run build`) command and it generates the build file.
after that you should got to firebase.json and put build folder in public directory

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/dist/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the last not the least firebase deploy. works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install things again, in my case, in `firebase.json`, I changed the value of `public` to `build/web` because I found `index.html` located in `project/build/web` folder.

Thank you all!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

- Delete .firebase folder
- Delete .firebaserc
- Delete firebase.json

Now run as follow:

```
$ firebase init hosting
? File build/web/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
$ firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Answer (score -1):

firebase init hosting
? File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
npm run build
firebase deploy --only hosting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).