# FireBase not hosting index.html

Tags: firebase-hosting

So I have followed all the steps and I am sure my steps are correct but still firebase is not hosting my index.html. it is showing default index.html which doesn't even exists. I have only index.html under my root folder and no matter how many times I do 'firebase init', it says that the project is hosted but no json file or dist file or any other file is ever created.

firebase login
firebase init
your-build-command-here
firebase deploy

Tried all the above steps but didnt work. Need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your html into a public/index.html directory

and type n when firebase asked you to override your index.html file

[image]

follow the steps given in below Url.

https://medium.com/@aleemuddin13/how-to-host-static-website-on-firebase-hosting-for-free-9de8917bebf2

you try these fixes as well.

[Firebase not running index.html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486069/firebase-not-running-index-html-file)